# UserManager.CreateAsync does not generate Id

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-identity-2

I just upgraded my MVC 5 application (was previously MVC 3 with `SimpleMembership`) to ASP.NET Identity 2.0 and I can work with existing users, but when I execute the following to create a new user:

```
var user = new ApplicationUser();
//user.Id = db.Users.Max(u => u.Id) + 1;    //does not help
user.UserName = model.UserName;
user.Email = model.EMailAddress;
var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
```

I get the following:

> System.Data.Entity.Core.UpdateException: An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details. ---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'Id', table 'MyDB.dbo.AspNetUsers'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.
>   The statement has been terminated.

**Does anyone have an idea why this is happening?**

This is my `UserManager`:

```
var manager = new ApplicationUserManager(new ApplicationUserStore(context.Get<MyDbContext>()));

manager.UserValidator = new UserValidator<ApplicationUser, int>(manager)
{
    AllowOnlyAlphanumericUserNames = false,
    RequireUniqueEmail = true
};

manager.PasswordValidator = new PasswordValidator
{
    RequiredLength = 6,
    RequireNonLetterOrDigit = false,
    RequireDigit = false,
    RequireLowercase = false,
    RequireUppercase = false,
};

manager.EmailService = new EmailService();

var dataProtectionProvider = options.DataProtectionProvider;
if (dataProtectionProvider != null)
{
    manager.UserTokenProvider = new DataProtectorTokenProvider<ApplicationUser, int>(dataProtectionProvider.Create("ASP.NET Identity"));
}
```

I use `int` keys for the users and roles, but I had the default `string`-keys before and there the `Id` was also not filled and I got a similar error.

Comment: What does your `ApplicationUser` class look like?

Comment: @DavidG: `public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser<int, ApplicationUserLogin, ApplicationUserRole, ApplicationUserClaim>` - all the `Application*`-classes have the `int`-key and some custom properties.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found the problem:
Because I changed the key from `string` to `int` the following migration was created:

```
AlterColumn("dbo.AspNetUsers", "Id", c => c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true));
```

There it correctly generated `identity: true`, BUT MSSQL can't convert an existing column to an identity column => the column became a "normal `INT` column".
Identity must then asume that the column is an identity column and inserts `null` as the key and expects the DB to generate the id => exception.

The solution was to revert back to my `SimpleMembership` DB from an old backup and directly convert it to `ASP.NET Identity` using the `int`-key when creating the `AspNetUsers`-table.

P.S.: But I still don't know why I had similar problems with `string`-keys, but I like the `int`-keys better anyhow...

Comment: Owing to your discovery, I deleted the Migrations files and deleted the tables and ran Update-Database, which worked.

Comment: do you have a solution using sql to update the columns instead? i am running it on a live server, dropping is not an option..

Comment: `dropping is not an option` - but it is the only one. But you can create a new column and then just drop the old column and not the whole table...

Answer (score 0):

Just ran into this issue, and it wasn't immediately clear to me what to do to solve it while keeping the migrations, so I'm adding this answer as a further clarification to what @ChrFin mentioned in his comment.

If you switched to `Int` Id from `Guid` through a migration, this is what you have to modify in the given migration to create tables on which `UserManager.Create()` won't fail:

```cs
//AlterColumn("dbo.AspNetRoles", "Id", c => c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true));
DropColumn("dbo.AspNetRoles", "Id");
AddColumn("dbo.AspNetRoles", "Id", c => c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true));

// ...

//AlterColumn("dbo.AspNetUsers", "Id", c => c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true));
DropColumn("dbo.AspNetUsers", "Id");
AddColumn("dbo.AspNetUsers", "Id", c => c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true));
```

**Additional information on the correction needed, to answer a comment:**

These modifications go in the `Up()` method of the auto-generated migration file. Basically, if you have this issue, you should be able to find the commented line `AlterColumn("dbo.AspNetRoles", "Id", c => c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true));` (or the equivalent thereof), if you search for it in your solution.

The migration file's `Up()` method will contain other lines/operations too, but they can be left as is, and only the above two needs to be overridden.

I'm actually not been working with ASP.NET MVC for a while (switched to Core), but from what I can recall, the migrations can be executed with the `Updade-Database` command in the Package Manager command line.

**But**, of course, first you have to roll back the last migration (the unmodified one, that caused the problem). From what I can recall, rolling back to a previous migration is done with the `Update-Database -TargetMigration:"migration_name"` command, where `migration_name` is the name of the preceding, still good migration.

Comment: I think this is what I need to do. Do these go inside the up method? And how to I run it once modified?

Comment: @SendETHToThisAddress sorry, my reply was too long to send as a comment, so I added it to the end of the answer. :) I hope it clarifies it.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem after switching to int Id from Guid (random string) but I was able to solve it in a different way. I was able to use the SQL Server Object Explorer (SSOE). I opened the SSOE, found my database and expanded the tables, and right-clicked dbo.AspNetUsers >View Designer. I saw that Id was an int, which I thought was correct but actually it should be uniqueIdentifier. I tried to change the data type to uniqueIdentifier but could not. When I clicked Update it was unsuccessful, it gave me an error message about it being referenced as a foreign key in other tables. It listed 3 tables I think, and if you follow the trail it leads to the table **dbo.AspNetUserClaims**. aspNetUserClaims designer

[image: aspNetUserClaims designer]

If you change the UserId field here to uniqueIdentifier it will cascade and change the data type in the other tables as well, all the way back to AspNetUsers.

[image: aspNetUserClaims uniqueIdentifier]